# Does sprite disposition affects rendering performance?

Tags: css, image, image-processing, css-sprites

In my application I have some very big sprites and have to decide between horizontal or vertical sprites. I've read that [horizontal sprites are smaller in file size](http://www.computertechtips.net/46/css-sprites-speed-up-your-site/), but I wonder if one of them would render faster.

My hypothesis is that if in browser memory the pixels are disposed line by line, then each image of an horizontal sprite would be sparsely distributed and so require several memory copies to render, while in a vertical sprite each image would be contained in a continuous memory segment.

Would this choice affect rendering performance?

Comment: I doubt that this is something you can actually _notice_...

Comment: It's worth noticing the nature of my application. My interface has a knob that was designed in 3D and rendered in 180 different positions. User will drag the mouse to rotate the knob, so the background position will be changed several times/second. Sometimes the images are not rendered fast enough, so user sees a big "jump" in knob position, instead of a continuous rotation.

Comment: I can't help thinking, it might be a better plan to import the 3d vector output into adobe illustrator and export it as javascript using the ai2canvas plugin.
Depending on your image sizes, it would more than half the rendering speed.